# How to copy a damaged file? (windows 7)

Tags: windows-7, data-recovery, file-transfer

I am trying to copy a 1GB .vob file, and in the middle of copying it says "can't copy the file - retry?"

I can open the file and play it (at least part way).  I imagine the file is damaged, is there a way  to "fix" it ?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I don't think you can fix a corrupted file but you can copy it. [Roadkil's Unstoppable Copier](http://www.roadkil.net/program.php/P29/Unstoppable%20Copier) can recover every readable piece of a file and put the pieces together. Using this method most types of files can be made useable even if some parts of the file were not recoverable in the end.

Comment: HI Mehper, I am using it now.  Thank you for the help, if it works I will mark your answer as the solution :)

Comment: OK, good luck with it :)

Comment: Two hours later, and it is still copying (641 read errors from the file)

Comment: Maybe you can add a remark about the time needed. It took me almost 7 hours to go through 400kb of bad sectors, and the regular time to copy the 1.2Gb remaining. At the end, it worked very good.

Comment: Awesome tip! Roadkil's Unstoppable Copier just saved the day and hours worth of rebuilding corrupt VM images.

Answer (score 1):

Is there any way to *"fix"* a partially copied file? No.

You could attempt to recopy it.

If the original is damaged, you are more screwed then not. There is a host of [data recovery software](http://www.google.com/search?q=data+recovery+software&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&aq=t&rls=org.mozilla:en-US:official&client=firefox-a) the that assumes the file was simply erased, not damaged bits.